# Which species has the highest proportion of homosexual individuals?

Tags: zoology, sex

Are there more homosexual individuals in ducks, humans, or some other species?

Comment: 100% of male flour beetles are bisexual.

Answer (score 3):

Homosexual behavior have been observed more than 1500 species (according to [Museum of Natural History of the University of Oslo](http://www.nhm.uio.no/besok-oss/utstillinger/skiftende/againstnature/index-eng.html)). A full comparison between all known species is far beyond the scope of this site, but below I discuss three species of interest. Also, the details of what counts as an homosexual behavior, and also whether you compute incidence or prevalence makes the whole discussion semantically complicated.

- According to [Simon Levay](https://www.amazon.ca/Gay-Straight-Reason-Why-Orientation/dp/0190297379) and [Aldo Polani](https://books.google.ca/books?id=EftT_1bsPOAC&pg=PA179&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), in domesticated sheep, 10% of the rams (males) prefer mating with other rams than with ewes (females).
- About 25% of black swans are homosexuals ([Braithwaite, 1981](http://www.publish.csiro.au/wr/WR9810135)).
- In lions, 8% of the mounting is in between two males ([Bagemihl 2000](https://www.amazon.ca/Biological-Exuberance-Homosexuality-Natural-Diversity/dp/031225377X))

In humans, around 3%-5% of the surveyed people claim being homosexual or bi-sexual (see [wiki > demographics of sexual orientation#Modern_survey_results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_sexual_orientation#Modern_survey_results)).

Comment: Any evidence (link) for the claim of the 1500? Otherwise nice answer!

Comment: @RHA Reference added. I would not call it an evidence as it is not a peer reviewed paper though. Thank you

Comment: Good enough (and +1), I just knew you hadn't made that number up yourself.